# How to show items from a listview group when selected from combobox

Tags: c#, listview, combobox

I am trying to display items in a listview from groups and here is what I mean.
I added a listview to a form and in the listview I added a 2 groups then I added items and for the items I chose a group name.

Now in a combox box I add in the selectindexchanged event I put this.

```
 if (comboBox1.Text == "group1")
        {
            foreach (string itemname1 in listimages.Groups[0].Items)
            {
                string currentitem = itemname1;
            }


        }
```

nothing is working so I am trying to figure out what I am not doing right.

The items in the combobox have the same items as group names.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Here is what I did

First on the listview I added Groups, then I added items and on the items in the Tag property I put in the group I wanted it to be linked to.

In the comboBox I put in group names as I typed them when I added them to the listview.

Then I added this code :

```
             private void frmImageSelection_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        items = new ListViewItem[listimages.Items.Count];
        listimages.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
        ShowGroup(0);
        cmbgroups.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }


            private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ShowGroup(cmbgroups.SelectedIndex);
    }

    void ShowGroup(int index)
    {
        if (index == 0) // all
        {
            listimages.Items.Clear();
            listimages.Items.AddRange(items);
        }
        else
        {
            listimages.Items.Clear();
            foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
                if (listimages.Groups[index].Name.Equals(item.Tag))
                    listimages.Items.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listimages.Items)
            item.Group = listimages.Groups[index];
    }

    ListViewItem[] items;
```

Anyway if you are not sure I will be glad to help you out just drop me a message in my inbox or something.